# Upload file using Ajax in custom form in Magento

Tags: php, file-upload, content-management-system, magento-1.7

I have created a Custom Module for admin in Magento.

I am using a form and I have a file field in that form.

How I can upload image using Ajax in my custom module in Magento.

I have searched on Google but didn't find any perfect solution.

Somebody please suggest me what to do.?